# WCF Ria Service:How to change the relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

Suppose I have 3 tables:
Employee(id1, ...)
Department(id2, ...)
EmployeeDepartment(id1, id2, datecreated, ...)

I have following kind data senario:

Employee:
(1, 'BoB', ...)

Department:
(1, 'HR')
(2, 'Marketing')
(3, 'Development')

EmployeeDepartment:
(1, 1, '2011-01-01')

In UI for Employee data form, there is a combobox to allow user change the employee department.

So now I want to change this employee department to Marketing, it means:
(1, 1, '2011-01-01')->(1, 2, '2011-01-01')

So logically, I should update entity EmployeeDepartment(1, 1, '2011-01-01').
If I use following code:
EmployeeDepartment.id2 = 2;
then submitchanges, I will get error: can not change the key.

Then try another way: delete (1, 1, '2011-01-01') and then add (1, 2, '2011-01-01'):
EmployeeDepartments.Remove( (1, 1, '2011-01-01'));
EmployeeDepartments.Add( new (1, 2, '2011-01-01'));

then submit changes, In database, I have two records in EmployeeDepartment:
(1, 1, '2011-01-01')
(1, 2, '2011-01-01')

not one (1, 2, '2011-01-01').

how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about giving EmployeeDepartment its own key instead of the composite it currently has, and have foreign key relationships to employee and department on their respective ids.